# Nest can't resolve dependencies of InvestorProfileService

Tags: nestjs

I am facing an issue with dependency resolution in my NestJS application. I have two modules, InvestorProfileModule and LegacyUserModule, where InvestorProfileModule imports LegacyUserModule. The relevant code snippets are as follows:

InvestorProfileModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [LegacyUserModule],
  providers: [InvestorProfileResolver, InvestorProfileService, QuizAnswerService]
})
export class InvestorProfileModule {}
```

LegacyUserModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [LegacyUserService],
  exports: [LegacyUserService]
})
export class LegacyUserModule {}
```

When I run my application, I encounter the following error:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the InvestorProfileService (WarehouseService, ?, QuizAnswerService, EmailService, EventEmitter). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [1] is available in the InvestorProfileModule context.

The error suggests checking if InvestorProfileModule is a valid NestJS module, ensuring that Object (at index [1]) is part of the current InvestorProfileModule, or if it is exported from a separate @Module, ensuring that the module is imported within InvestorProfileModule.

I have tried various solutions, including checking the module validity, ensuring the correct import, and validating providers, but the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this dependency issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have my investor-profile.service like this :

```
    import { LegacyUserService } from 'libs/api/gateway/users/feature/src/lib/legacy.user.service'

@Injectable()
export class InvestorProfileService {
  constructor(
    private readonly warehouseService: WarehouseService,
    private legacyUserService: LegacyUserService,
    private readonly quizAnswerService: QuizAnswerService,
    private readonly emailService: EmailService,
    private readonly eventEmitter: EventEmitter2
  ) {}
```

Comment: Can you show the `InvestorProfileService`? Seems like you might be using an `interface` type for a provider instead of a class or specific injection token

Comment: Sure,  I've updated the post to include details about the InvestorProfileService

Comment: What is `LegacyUserService`? I would expect if it's a class to have proper metadata about it that Typescript can reflect